# Cannot convert Nan to Java.lang.long

Tags: javascript

```
TimeoutInterval = TimeoutInterval * 60 * 1000; //Converting to milisecond
TimeOutObj = setTimeout(function(){    

},TimeoutInterval);
```

What is wrong here, why i am getting this error  `Cannot convert Nan to Java.lang.long`.

Comment: What error? And what is the code inside the function?

Comment: the error is above in the title: Cannot convert Nan to Java.lang.long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  var TimeoutInterval = 1;
  TimeoutInterval = TimeoutInterval * 60 * 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
var TimeoutInterval = 1;
TimeoutInterval = TimeoutInterval * 60 * 1000; //Converting to milisecond
var TimeOutObj = setTimeout(function(){},TimeoutInterval);
```